# Error in Visual Studio 2022 C++ Qt project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, exception, rtsp

I am working on a C++ project on Visual Studio 2022 with Qt and OpenCV.
I am using VideoCapture to open an rtsp stream using the open() function.

However, I get an exception as follows when I try to open the rtsp stream:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB37BB4F69 in faulty.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000029218FF9F0.
The thread 0x45d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
string un = port_ipDialog->devInfo.szUserName;
string stri = "rtsp://" + un + ":" + PWD + "@" + IP + "/gen/fakescreen?channel=5&subtype=2";
memcpy(rtsp, stri.c_str(), 256);
if (!capture.open(rtsp)) {
    QMessageBox::warning(nullptr, "notice", "fail!!", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Yes);
    return;
}
```

The strange thing is that the same thing is working perfectly on another computer.

Can someone give some insight into this exception and why it might be occurring?
I would be grateful.

Comment: when running under the debugger turn on 'break on exception thrown' for all excceptions. Debug>Windows>ExceptionSettings

Comment: @pm100 I did that, and now the program stops when this exception is reached. At that point a tab opens on visual studio stating that `igd10um64xe.pdb not loaded`. And the exception is the same `MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x000000F3576FFB10`

Comment: You need to look at the  stack trace window to what part of your code is causing the error

Comment: @pm100 Strangely there is no stacktrace, there is only the exception `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEB6E24F69 in Structure.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: ShaderCache::ShaderCacheFileBackedEmptyCacheFileException at memory location 0x00000013C4393070.`
And it points to the line `if(!capture.open(rtsp))`.
When I give it an api preference, like `cv::CAP_FFMPEG`, the exception disappears, but it enters this if loop, and fails to show the stream.

Answer (score 0):

well thi9s line invokes UB

```
 memcpy(rtsp, stri.c_str(), 256);
```

the input is shorter that 256, also what is the size of rtsp?

Why not use `strcpy`